# Path.equals() returns true for two different folders (lowercase m and uppercase M) on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, java-8, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've created a file indexer, which works well in Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Ever since I migrated to Windows 10, my code has been spitting errors on a specific folder, `C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo`

This folder is particular because it contains folders with lowercase and uppercase names which are identical if lowercased.

[image: screenshot of folder]

The problem is that I've looked through all of my codebase, and it has no instances of `equalsIgnoreCase` or `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase`.

At the end I concluded that `Path.equals` returns true for two different folders, which it shouldn't. This causes an issue in my code because `Path` is used as the key of `Map` about everywhere in the code, in particular, in my indexer implementation, this causes `Collectors.groupingBy` to group files belonging to different folders into the same folder:

```
    Map<Path, List<DetailedFileReference>> parentFolderToDetailList = finderResult.getDetails().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.asPathObject().getParent()));
```

I was able to figure out reproduction steps:

```
Path originFolder = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Terminal\\AppData\\Local\\lxss\\rootfs\\usr\\share\\terminfo");
Path lowercaseFolder = originFolder.resolve("m");
Path uppercaseFolder = originFolder.resolve("M");

if (lowercaseFolder.equals(uppercaseFolder)) {
    System.out.println(lowercaseFolder.toString() + " is equal to " + uppercaseFolder.toString());
}
```

This code prints:

```
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m is equal to C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M
```

However, it turns out other Java code do see the distinction between these two folders, as `Files.walk` just works fine:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class DuplicateFileIndexing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path originFolder = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Terminal\\AppData\\Local\\lxss\\rootfs\\usr\\share\\terminfo");
        Path lowercaseFolder = originFolder.resolve("m");
        Path uppercaseFolder = originFolder.resolve("M");

        System.out.println(originFolder.toAbsolutePath().toString());

        List<String> directoriesInOriginFolder = Files.walk(originFolder, 1)
                .filter(path -> Files.isDirectory(path))
                .map(path -> path.getFileName().toString())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(directoriesInOriginFolder);

        if (directoriesInOriginFolder.contains("m")) {
            System.out.println("Has a m folder");
        }
        if (directoriesInOriginFolder.contains("M")) {
            System.out.println("Has a M folder");
        }

        System.out.println("---");

        System.out.println("Files in 'm' folder");
        Files.walk(lowercaseFolder, 1)
                .map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().toString())
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("---");

        System.out.println("Files in 'M' folder");
        Files.walk(uppercaseFolder, 1)
                .map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().toString())
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("---");

        System.out.println("Parent of files in 'm' folder");
        Files.walk(lowercaseFolder, 1)
                .map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().toString() + " is a child of " + path.getParent().toString())
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("---");

        System.out.println("Parent of files in 'M' folder");
        Files.walk(uppercaseFolder, 1)
                .map(path -> path.toAbsolutePath().toString() + " is a child of " + path.getParent().toString())
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("---");

        if (lowercaseFolder.equals(uppercaseFolder)) {
            System.out.println(lowercaseFolder.toString() + " is equal to " + uppercaseFolder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo
[terminfo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, a, b, c, d, E, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, L, l, M, m, N, n, o, P, p, Q, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, X, x, z]
Has a m folder
Has a M folder
---
Files in 'm' folder
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m\MtxOrb
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m\MtxOrb162
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m\MtxOrb204
---
Files in 'M' folder
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M\MtxOrb
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M\MtxOrb162
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M\MtxOrb204
---
Parent of files in 'm' folder
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m\MtxOrb is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m\MtxOrb162 is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m\MtxOrb204 is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m
---
Parent of files in 'M' folder
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M\MtxOrb is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M\MtxOrb162 is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M\MtxOrb204 is a child of C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M
---
C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\m is equal to C:\Users\Terminal\AppData\Local\lxss\rootfs\usr\share\terminfo\M
```

According to the documentation, [Path.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Whether or not two path are equal depends on the file system implementation. In some cases the paths are compared without regard to case, and others are case sensitive.

How can I fix my code or the JVM so that `Path.equals` return false for two different folders differing by case?

---

Comment: EDIT: I messed up the Collectors.toMap code, but the question stands, I've removed it from the question

Comment: I just tried to create two folders in a Win10 machine with the same name and different cases, but neither in a terminal nor in Explorer I could do that. When trying to do the second create, I always get 'already exists'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pretty much every other location in NTFS, Path.equals would be right.  However, "LXSS" files were created using using something other than the normal Windows API (such as [NtCreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380(v=vs.85).aspx) using [OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557749(v=vs.85).aspx) not specifying OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE).

If you try browsing "M" and "m" in Windows, you'll notice that you can only get in one of them as they appear to have the same contents.  So not only are some parts of AppData difficult to differentiate, some parts are flat-out inaccessible without a bit of magic.

Comment: You're completely right, I did not notice how the contents of m and M were not able to be consistently opened in Windows Explorer (I thought they had the same content). I just tried on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and it shows drastically different contents.

Comment: To follow up, there's a better explanation of how all this stuff works at [this blog post](http://www.nicklowe.org/2012/02/understanding-case-sensitivity-in-windows-obcaseinsensitive-file_case_sensitive_search/).  Using FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS in [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) is one of their examples.  I suppose that NTFS could be thought of as either case-sensitive or case-insensitive depending on the application.

Comment: Since Java is not capable of listing the true contents of the two distinct folders, the question does not really stand anymore. I'll opt to ignore all folders which name conflicts with a sibling folder, since the indexer will never be able to index these folders properly anyways.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaDoc for `Path::equals` states:

> Whether or not two path are equal depends on the file system implementation. In some cases the paths are compared without regard to case, and others are case sensitive. This method does not access the file system and the file is not required to exist. Where required, the [isSameFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-) method may be used to check if two paths locate the same file.

Since your `Path`s are not tested with regards of the `FileSystem`, you should use [Files::isSameFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isSameFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-).

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a viable solution, Files.isSameFile requires access to the file system, and the part of the problem lies in Path being used as the key of Map. In my indexer code, all necessary calls to the file system are performed by the indexing process (i.e. collecting last modified date, sha256 hash), and the rest of the code do not assume they have access to the file system. The code where this issue occurs is responsible for creating a visual rendering of the filsystem.

Comment: @Hay. Since there is no guarantee of the equals method you should choose an other type as key e.g. String.

Comment: As it turns out, Files::isSameFile does not return the desired result, it returns `true`, because it is in fact the same directory in regards to Java; browsing each folder with Java NIO will reveal the same contents. Only WSL/Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is capable of navigating through the two distinct case-sensitive directories.